# How to include a console executable with a forms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, deployment, console-application

I'm brand new at doing this whole C# business... So please be gentle :)

I have been given a project where a client needs a method for scheduling a task that will fetch data from an API and print it, automatically. I've created a Windows form project, from which I set options for the schedule, then I use a 3rd party tool for actually creating and editing the schedule. This all works as expected.

The scheduled task invokes a console application I've written, also in C#. This receives arguments as specified in the scheduled task, and uses them to determine which URI to connect to, pull out the data, format it, and print it. This too, works exactly as expected.

My question is... How can I merge these projects together, so that a single install process installs all the required binaries. The clients that will be using this are not particularly savvy, but they can install a program and fill in some details in a form and click "apply". But it seems a bit unprofessional to ask them to install two programs.

Is there a way to achieve this? My Google-fu is failing me. Any search for the combination "c# windows form app console app" brings up page after page of irrelevant results... Any tips much appreciated!

Comment: I can see at least 2 solutions for your problem:

Comment: 1. If your software doesn't need a proper "c:\program file" kind of standard installation then include all your files in a zip file and hand it over to your client so that everything will be in place for them. 2. Create a setup project from Visual Studio where you can include all the files and much more into an installer and ask your client to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Perform the following steps to add the executable to your program's output:

1. Add the 3rd party executable to your project

   - It may be useful to put it in a "Tools" folder or similar
2. Set its "Copy to Output Directory" setting to "Copy Always" or "Copy if newer"

Now when you build your project, the required executable will be automatically included in the build output. When you write the installer, it should be putting all the build output on the client machine, so they automatically have the required 3rd party program!